# How to send MySQL data To fire-base database?

Tags: android, mysql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm setting up a home security system using Arduino with some Sensors. I used C language to coding to get sensor data. I already sent that data to MySQL database hosted in 000webhost. now I want to send MySQL data to firebase. (to get real-time data). after I will show firebase data in android app.

so how to do it correctly?

If I get Jason format of Mysql data how to send it to firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be linked or just imported? In case of the latter, firebase's realtime database has an import option.

- Go to the firebase console
- Go to the database settings, initialize the realtime database if necessary
- Click the 3 dots on the top right when you're viewing the database and click 'import JSON' and you're good to go

Comment: I need to link because the android app needs to shows real-time sensor data and notifications to the user.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic process here. Both MySQL and Firebase have API's, so you'll have to write code that read from MySQL and writes to Firebase.

Alternatively you can write straight to Firebase from your C++ code using either the C++ SDK for Firebase, or (more likely) the REST API).